# Unable to find function "upsilon"

Tags: r

I'm using the MBESS package and trying to use the upsilon function.  I'm getting an error that it cannot be found (specifically "Error: could not find function "upsilon""), although it's listed in the MBESS documentation (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MBESS/MBESS.pdf).  I tried help.search and it is not coming up anywhere, and I've tried searching R listserves but am not seeing that anyone else has noted this problem. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you run `library(MBESS)` before calling the function? And also, are you able to print the function in the console using `MBESS:::upsilon`? if yes, the author might have forgotten to export the function

Comment: I have MBESS loaded in the library and have ran other functions within it, so generally MBESS is working.  I tried MBESS:::upsilon and receive this message:  Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
  object 'upsilon' not found

Comment: you might want to search through the MBESS library folder to confirm that the upsilon function is missing before contacting the author.

Comment: I had no trouble in finding it in version 4.4.3 while running R 3.5.2 in Ubuntu 18.04. The code for `upsilon` makes extensive use of functions from the `lavaan` package. The R packages that MBESS Imports inlcude: `boot, gsl, lavaan, MASS, methods, mnormt, nlme, OpenMx, parallel, sem, semTools`